# POST http://localhost:3000/api/posts 500 (Internal Server Error) with MERN

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern, internal-server-error

I am building a project using MERN stack and I have no problem and the requests I send to print the post in the console are done correctly but suddenly it no longer appears and instead I get this error

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/posts 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

What I tried to do is:
I checked the IP number in the MongoDB database, and it was added correctly, and I turned off the backend server and restarted it, and it did not work.

Comment: if you sow my question and you don't know the answer . . . just  vote up